# Ways of writing jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any documented or some kind of standard way of writing jQuery code in any web application?

I am asking this more in the context of jQuery binding which is global and hence needs a slightly different way of writing than normal JavaScript code.

Please let me know how do we decide the right approach. As a simple example, should we write code to check for an `if (somevar)` and then write `$(someEle).mouseover()` or should it be reversed?

Please suggest.

Comment: That depends on whether you want to check `somevar` only once, when binding your handler, or every time the mouse pointer hovers over the element. The two forms are not interchangeable.

Comment: *"jQuery binding which is global"* - could you elaborate? (Also, as compared to what?)

Comment: What i mean is like lets say a jQuery click binding, it would fire irrespective of where the code is written..it won't check for anything else..

Comment: @test But that's in no way different from standard (non-jQuery) event handler binding (with `addEventListener`). I don't see how jQuery is special here...

Comment: I DO NOT KNOW IF YOU ACTUALLY UNDERSTOOD THE QUESTION..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's the idea of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) which says that you don't allow JavaScript to  creep into your HTML.

So rather than having any onclick="doSomethingInJS()" in there, you should do all of your binding elsewhere. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#somthingToBeClickedUpon").click(doSomethingInJS());
});
```

That's one factor. Another is to separate your JavaScript and CSS out from your HTML so they're in separate files. That's a recommendation that you'll get when you run Yahoo's YSlow on your site.

Anything beyond that in structuring your JS, we'll need to know more about what the code does.

Comment: Thx john..you atleast understood the question..